# effects of combining eclipse jee and php together

Tags: java, php, eclipse, web

I am currently using eclipse jee and am installing the php plugin onto it.By doing so will I be able to use java files and php files within the same project?

Comment: yes, you can do it even without any plugin

Comment: another question that i have is i am using a contact form which sends data using sendmail.php page used in the action .So do i have to create the php page in the src folder or the web content folder? also is there a way to send contact form data via jsp or servlet?